# Airflow through tube

Tags: flow, aerodynamics, air, fan

I have a tube with an inline fan moving 100 cfm (cubic feet per minute). If I add an additional fan in the same tube capable of moving 100 cfm, what would happen? Would I increase my cfm to 200? Would my cfm stay the same? Would my cfm increase slightly?

Comment: So you have a setup with two fans inline with each other? Or two inputs into one tube, each input with an inline fan?

Comment: My setup is one tube with two fans inline in the same tube.